# Equivalence norm and absolute value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to know if the norm of a real valued function with more variable, like: $\left \| f(x,y)\right\|$ is equal to its absolute value $|f(x,y)|$.

Thanks to all.

Comment: How are you defining "norm of a real-valued function"?

Comment: Well, since it's real-valued, you just take its absolute value.